# Finding Item's distribution over customer routes

Tags: sql-server

Please help me to find a solution.

I have two tables [CustomerMaster and SalesData] as shown below.

### CustomerMaster

```
| CODE |       NAME | ROUTE | DIVISION |
|------|------------|-------|----------|
| 1001 |  Customer1 |    R1 |     Div1 |
| 1002 |  Customer2 |    R1 |     Div1 |
| 1003 |  Customer3 |    R1 |     Div1 |
| 1004 |  Customer4 |    R2 |     Div1 |
| 1005 |  Customer5 |    R2 |     Div1 |
| 1006 |  Customer6 |    R2 |     Div1 |
| 1007 |  Customer7 |    R3 |     Div2 |
| 1008 |  Customer8 |    R3 |     Div2 |
| 1009 |  Customer9 |    R3 |     Div2 |
| 1010 | Customer10 |    R4 |     Div2 |
```

### SalesData

```
| CUSTOMERCODE |               DATE | ITEM | BRAND | QUANTITY |
|--------------|--------------------|------|-------|----------|
|         1001 |  January, 01 2014  |  IT1 |   BR1 |        2 |
|         1001 | February, 01 2014  |  IT2 |   BR2 |        5 |
|         1003 |  January, 01 2014  |  IT1 |   BR1 |       20 |
|         1003 | February, 01 2014  |  IT3 |   BR1 |        6 |
|         1005 |  January, 01 2014  |  IT1 |   BR1 |        5 |
|         1005 | February, 01 2014  |  IT2 |   BR2 |       11 |
|         1007 |  January, 01 2014  |  IT1 |   BR1 |       15 |
|         1007 | February, 01 2014  |  IT2 |   BR2 |        7 |
|         1007 |    March, 01 2014  |  IT3 |   BR1 |        9 |
|         1007 |    April, 01 2014  |  IT4 |   BR2 |       18 |
```

---

I need to answer below questions

To get the Brand distribution over Route and Division

- ex:BR1 reached 2 customers out of 3 in R1
- ex:BR1 reached 3 customers out of 6 in Div1

To get the Item distribution over Route and Division

- ex:IT2 reached 1 customers out of 3 in R1
- ex:IT2 reached 2 customers out of 6 in Div1

I am looking for something like this

```
| Item  |  Brand|Route  | Division  | TotalCustomersCount   | BuyingCustomersCount|
|-------|-------|-------|-----------|-----------------------|---------------------|
| IT2   |BR2    |R1     | Div1      |                   3   |                   1 |
| IT2   |BR2    |R4     | Div1      |                   1   |                   0 |
| IT1   |BR2    |R1     | Div1      |                   3   |                   2 |
|       |       |       |           |                       |                     |
```

I am trying some queries like

```
select s.item,s.brand,c.division,c.route,
TotalCustomersCount=(select COUNT(distinct  x.CODE) from  CustomerMaster x where x.Route=c.route),
BuyingCustomersCount=(select COUNT(distinct y.CUSTOMERCODE) from  SalesData y where y.CustomerCode=c.Code and y.item=s.Item )
from CustomerMaster c join SalesData s on c.code=s.customercode
```

It will be a great if someone can help me.
My logic is wrong?

Answer (score -1):

```
select sd.item, 
       sd.brand,
       cm.Route,
       cm.Route, 
       count(*) as TotalCustomersCount 
from SalesData sd with (nolock)
  inner join CustomerMaster cm 
    on sd.CUSTOMERCODE=cm.CODE
group by cm.ROUTE
```

I am not sure what `BuyingCustomersCount` is.

Comment: :Your query will return the Routes which have sales.BuyingCustomersCount means 'No of customers' buying that item in that Route.